# Node.js filesystem сделать цикл для каждой строки

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет. Есть файл users.txt, он содержит следующее:

```
email@asdasd.ru:ashasdjh
email@asdhs.ru:gjdfgjdf
asddfj@asdf.ru:sjsdfk
```

Сделал банальный fs.watch, который отслеживает любое изменение в файле. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать цикл, который будет делать следующие действия:

```
*открыть файл*
 *цикл для каждой строки*
  *записываем все, что было до : в массив users[i].email, что после - users[i].password
*закрываем файл*
```

Как правильно сделать такой цикл? Как работать со строками в файлах?

P.S. скрипт fs.watch:

```
fs.watchFile('users.txt', function(curr, prev) {
  var file_handle = fs.openSync("users.txt", "r", 0644);
  var data = fs.readSync(file_handle, 10000, null, 'ascii');
  console.log(data);
fs.closeSync(file_handle);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const filename = 'users.txt';
const users = [];
fs.watch(filename, () => {
    const text = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString();
    users.push(...text.split('\n').map(str => {
        email: str.split(':')[0].trim(),
        password: str.split(':')[1].trim()
    }));
    console.log(users);
});
```